# Jquery table html outputting incorrectly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the below jQuery taking in the response from an AJAX request to build a table, however the each seems to get fired after the append below it, how do I insure that the table is not closed until the each is complete.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "api/getFirmTabletsDetails.php",
    data: "id=" + firmID,
    cache: false,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(result)
    {
        var tabletArea = modal.find('#tablet-body');
        tabletArea.html("");
        tabletArea.append
        (
            '<div class="col-lg-12">
             <table class="table table-hover table-striped"><thead>
             <tr><th>Name</th><th>Status</th><th>Address</th></tr>
             </thead><tbody>'
        );
        if (result.success = 1)
        {
            $.each(result.request, function( index, value )
            {
                var address = value.Street + "<br>" + value.Street2 + "<br>" 
                              + value.Town + "<br>" + value.County +  "<br>" 
                              + value.Postcode;
                tabletArea.append('<tr><td>'+value.Name+
                '</td><td>'+value.Status+'</td><td>'+address+'</td></tr>');
            });
        }else{
            alert(result.error);
        }
        tabletArea.append('</tbody></table></div></div>');
    }
});
```

Output:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="modal-body" id="tablet-body">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <table class="table table-hover table-striped">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Status</th>
              <th>Address</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
        </table>
      </div>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>...</td>
          <td>...</td>
          <td>...
          <br />...
          <br />...
          <br />...
          <br />...</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>...</td>
          <td>...</td>
          <td>...
          <br />...
          <br />...
          <br />...
          <br />...</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You are using [`append`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) method incorrectly.

As you can read in the official documentation, `append( content )` takes a parameter which can be `DOM element, text node, array of elements and text nodes, HTML string, or jQuery object to insert at the end of each element in the set of matched elements.` What you are doing here is passing pieces of strings repeatedly. You should instead pass the complete htmlString for the element that is to be appended. If you want to take an approach similar to what you are doing already, you can keep a string and keep adding elements to it. Once you are done, you can pass the string to your `append(content)` method **once**. Check the code given below:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "api/getFirmTabletsDetails.php",
    data: "id=" + firmID,
    cache: false,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(result){
        var tabletArea = modal.find('#tablet-body');
        tabletArea.html("");
        var htmlString = "";
        htmlString += '<div class="col-lg-12"><table class="table table-hover table-striped"><thead><tr><th>Name</th><th>Status</th><th>Address</th></tr></thead><tbody>';
        if (result.success = 1){
            $.each(result.request, function( index, value ) {

            var address = value.Street + "<br>" + value.Street2 + "<br>" + value.Town + "<br>" + value.County + "<br>" + value.Postcode;

            htmlString += '<tr><td>'+value.Name+'</td><td>'+value.Status+'</td><td>'+address+'</td></tr>';

            });
        }else{
            alert(result.error);
        }
        htmlString += '</tbody></table></div></div>';

        tabletArea.append( htmlString );

    }
    });
```

Comment: +1 .Just to mention, @Zac
as anticipated the `each` append runs before the last `append` . and
why using `append` was wrong in question because when we insert to document, browser assumes some tags for us when they are not complete.